# How do I make a sprite character jump with pyglet on update method?

Tags: python, pyglet

I'm learning some game dev intro and I'm using python's pyglet to implement a Mario like game. I'd like to make Mario jump smoothly, but I'm having some trouble with it. 
He is jumping and if I keep the jump button (space) pressed it floats on the air and looks bugged.

How do I make Mario jump smoothly (a normal Mario jump)?

Here is my player class update method code:

```
def update(self, dt):

    super(Player, self).update(dt)

    if not self.dead:
        if self.keys['left']:

            self.set_animation(direction="left")

            if self.actual_direction == "right" or self.actual_direction == "stop":
                self.actual_direction = "left"
                self.update_image()

            self.x -= 2.5

        if self.keys['right']:

            self.set_animation(direction="right")

            if self.actual_direction == "left" or self.actual_direction=="stop":
                self.actual_direction = "right"
                self.update_image()

            self.x += 2.5


        if self.keys['space']:


            if self.actual_direction == "left":
                self.set_animation(direction="left")
                self.update_image()

            if self.actual_direction == "right":
                self.set_animation(direction="right")
                self.update_image()

            if self.y < 350:
                self.y +=10
            else:
                self.y -=10

        else:
            if self.y > self.floor:
                self.y -= 10
            else:
                self.y = self.floor
```

Comment: If you want your jump to look realistic use some basic physics. Have a variable to track the sprite's velocity. Whenever the character is not on the floor, apply gravity (subtract vertical velocity).  When you press jump (using the on_key_press event instead of manually polling self.keys) apply large upward velocity once. Your question really isn't pyglet specific, and I suggest looking up some basic platform game tutorials.

Comment: It turned out I found another solution. But thanks a lot!